# ¿Como obtener informacion del fabricante de disco duro C#?

Tags: c#, informacion

Estoy trabajando con C# y necesito obtener la informacion del fabricante de los discos duros.

Mas puntualmente el nombre del disco duro (o si es posible si es un hdd o un m.2) como en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya he probado con estos dos metodos pero ninguno me muestra esa info.

- https://fermasmas.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/cmo-obtener-el-nmero-serial-del-disco-duro-y-ms/
- https://ourcodeworld.co/articulos/leer/294/como-obtener-informacion-basica-y-avanzada-de-hardware-y-software-gpu-disco-duro-procesador-sistema-operativo-impresoras-en-winforms-con-c-sharp

Gracias

Comment: Por favor incluye el código que has escrito intentando resolver el problema

Comment: en ese momento no tenia ningun codigo... lo unico era lo de los post ¬¬ igual ya quedo resuelto con la respuesta de Jaime Mendez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente agrega el Nuget [`System.Management`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management) a tu proyecto. Luego usa algo como:

```
using System.Management;

var disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
foreach (ManagementObject disk in disks.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(disk["Model"]);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que esta solución solo es válida para windows.

Comment: Gracias man!!!!, era justo lo que necesitaba (Aunque habia llegado a la misma respuesta hace un par de horas, le atino a lo mismo)